# CSS Keyframe animation along with screen height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate an object in second page from one position to another using the below code.

```
#myimg2{

    position: absolute;
    -webkit-animation: myfirst2 3s none; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-direction: top; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: myfirst2 3s none;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes myfirst2 {
    0%   { left: 10%; top: 1325px;}
    100% { left: 10%; top: 1285px;}
}
```

Here, I have hardcoded top and it is working perfectly fine. 
I can extract the height of the screen using

```
var hgt = $('#img1').height();
```

Can anyone suggest how i can set this var+40 as top for 100 percent animation and var for 0 percent animation rather than hardcoding with 1325 and 1285 respectively

Comment: You can take a look at https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes, in here if you put that script at the end of your HTML, you can create the webkit keyframes right insie the jquery code, and you can mix variables with the top of other elements.